# previously logged d3 object doesn't show its __data__ property after removing __data__ with datum(num)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>datum</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>datum</h1>

    <svg width="200" height="300">
        <circle cx="100" cy="50"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="150"></circle>
        <circle cx="100" cy="250"></circle>
    </svg>
    <svg>

    </svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="selection_datum.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

jvascript code

```
let allCircles = d3.selectAll('svg').selectAll('circle');

let radius = 25;

allCircles.datum(radius);
console.log(allCircles); // __data__ doesn't exist.
console.log(allCircles.datum()); // 25

allCircles.datum(null); // remove __data__
console.log(allCircles);
```

I bound a primitive data `25` into d3 objects by using `datum()` method.
and I logged `allCircles.datum()`. It showed `25`.

But first console log, `console.log(allCircles)` didn't show `__data__` property.
Even tho the next console log `console.log(allCircles.datum())` tells me it returns `25`

why the first console log doesn't show me `__data__` property?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `__data__` property is returned, under the first array of `__groups` in the object. You can read them all like this:

```
let allCirclesNodes = allCircles['_groups'][0];
 
for (i=0; i < allCirclesNodes.length; i++) { 
   console.log(allCirclesNodes[i]['__data__']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks you are right but It's very weird.. because if you check my code on the browser, you can't see _ _data_ _ as a property of the object. I think datum(null) did something.

Comment: In my experience, I've found that the browser console will update any variables to show their current state.